# Retrieve youtube ID in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, regex

I have this foreach loop :

```
<?php foreach($dataRepeatableField as $key => $value){
    echo '<div data-video="'. $value['youtubeid'].'" class="video-thumb">'. $value['nom'].'</div>';
} ?>
```

youtubeid is the Youtube ID from $dataRepeatableField array. I need the possibility instead of use only the Youtube ID, use an URL like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID and retrieve only the ID.

I found this code :

```
<?php
preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
$youtube_id = $match[1];
?>
```

But i don't know how do that in an array ?

Example array

```
Array ( [canaux0] => Array ( [nom] => Plénières [youtubeid] => vA6mmyl1nNQ ) [canaux1] => Array ( [nom] => Conférences [youtubeid] => U2iS0O-reEE ) [canaux2] => Array ( [nom] => Battle [youtubeid] => RonjPhIzUcQ ) [canaux3] => Array ( [nom] => Focus [youtubeid] => W3fnsrYUjQk ) [canaux4] => Array ( [nom] => Plein Air [youtubeid] => 4PMC_vlsvPo ) [canaux5] => Array ( [nom] => Retour d'Expériences [youtubeid] => VNo3iWSoxT0 ) [canaux6] => Array ( [nom] => Les mains dans le cambouis [youtubeid] => USyaS9gDGwE ) [canaux7] => Array ( [nom] => Session Startups [youtubeid] => 4PMC_vlsvPo ) )
```

Comment: Please share an example array.

Comment: What you got there, takes the input text to match from `$url`. So you replace _that_ part, which whatever accesses the specific array element you want to apply this to …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
foreach($dataRepeatableField as $key => $value){
    // using $value['youtube_url'] instead of $value['youtubeid']
    preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $value['youtube_url'], $match);
    $youtube_id = $match[1];
    echo '<div data-video="'. $youtube_id .'" class="video-thumb">'. $value['nom'].'</div>';
}
?>
```

This should do it.